# Duplicate entry for key phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to insert new rows in my table and I got an erro I never had before, no idea why, this is it:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '24' for key 'usuario_id_2'
```

My query:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`votos` (`id`, `usuario_id`, `ciudad_candidata_id`, `voto`) VALUES (NULL, '24', '1', '1')
```

`usuario_id` is a foreign key, I have used it before in other tables and never had this problem. I don't understand what the error means and why it's happening.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that the `usuario_id` column is declared to be unique in the `votos` table, and there's already a row with `24` in that column. If it's not supposed to be unique in this table, fix your table schema. You probably should configure it with an ordinary index, not a unique index.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was driving me crazy! I must have slipped my finger when configuring that constraint and I didn't see it...